# How do you determine the version of OCaml or Jane Street Core library at runtime

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-core

I am migrating to a recent version of OCaml (and Jane Street's Core modules), but would like my code to continue to compile with older versions. To do so, I would like to create a module with portable functions that map to either the old or new interfaces depending on the version. Querying both the version of OCaml and the version of Jane Street Core would work.

How can we look up the version of the compiler or of Jane Street Core *at runtime*? I know that I could pass the output of `ocamlopt --version` via my build system, but ideally I should not have to invoke my programs in a special way.

Comment: To clarify: you're looking for a way for your program to get this information at runtime?

Comment: Yes, I would like to get this information at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the OCaml version number with `Sys.ocaml_version`.

```
utop # Sys.ocaml_version;;
- : string = "4.13.1"
```

I'm afraid after browsing the Jane Street [Base](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/base/Base/index.html) and [Core](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/core/Core/index.html) API docs, I don't see a way to query the version number at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to answer a slightly different question, but that might be a XY problem: if you want to build a compatibility package, determining the version of packages at runtime doesn't really help because something like

```
let f = if Sys.ocaml_version > ... then new_function else compat_function
```

requires `new_function` to exist independently of the runtime value of `Sys.ocaml_version`.

A common solution for compatibility package is to detect version earlier at build time with cppo for instance or using some code generation, see for instance https://github.com/janestreet/result or https://github.com/ocaml/stdlib-shims.

Answer (score 2):

You could use
`Config.version` from `Compiler_libs` as documented here https://ocaml.org/api/compilerlibref/Config.html.

**Note** this warning from Compiler_libs:

> This library is part of the internal OCaml compiler API, and is not
> the language standard library. There are no compatibility guarantees
> between releases, so code written against these modules must be
> willing to depend on specific OCaml compiler versions.